# Installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, but its not compatible with my project ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC). Is there any way to get around this issue?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, nuget

I've installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types latest version (14.0.1016.290). But then I received the Warning:

Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.1016.290' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

So my question is if it is possible to get around this issue in any means? Or if the only way is to change the project's target frameworks?

Comment: As the error says, the library you tried to use is for .NET Framework, not .NET Core. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need it in my current lib because I'm using the following code:  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();. I then wonder if I need to change target or if I can get around the problem?

Comment: SqlConnection is NOT defined in SqlTypes at all. It's part of the older System.Data.SqlClient or its replacement, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient packages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Great! I Installed System.Data.SqlClient and its fully compatible. The connection is now defined. I did not need the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package at all. Thanks for clearing up the differences between the older version and its replacement!

Comment: The current version is Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. All newer packages expect this, not `System.Data.SqlClient` and will install it if they don't find it.